# Black Screen Issue

Tags: drivers, 22.04, crash

I have been suffering this issue for a long time. I know this is not first time asking this question but I could not figure out what causes that problem ,and how to solve it.
My Laptop Model is ASUS TUF Gaming A15 FA506II
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.19.0-41-generic
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon G
GPU: AMD ATI 05:00.0 Renoir
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile
I want to make clear my Problem. Sometimes my computer instantly goes black screen while everything seems fine. And sometimes If there is sound that playing it goes an infinite loop.

Comment: What is a long time? 3 days, 6 months? What driver are you using for the NVIDIA card and have you tried others?

Comment: About 5 mounts. Ubuntu's nvidia-driver-525. Yeah other does not even sees my gpu.